# MYSQL Server is getting restarted multiple times every 2-3 days

Tags: mysql

Mysql Server is getting restarted saying below errors. It will be grateful if someone can help me to solve this.

```
2017-10-04 17:07:43 3402 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 1048548 bytes)
2017-10-04 17:07:44 3402 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 1048548 bytes)
2017-10-04 17:07:46 3402 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 1048548 bytes)
2017-10-04 17:07:48 3402 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 1048548 bytes)
2017-10-04 17:07:49 3402 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 1048548 bytes)
2017-10-04 17:07:51 3402 [ERROR] InnoDB: InnoDB: Unable to allocate memory of size 1065016.

2017-10-04 17:07:51 993b90 InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 10042256 in file ha_innodb.cc line 17352
```

Using 32bit centos system as database server.

Tried increasing max connections, innodb_buffer_size but did not help.

Comment: What do "top" and "ps" show? How much physical memory does the machine have? How much swap? Why aren't you using 64bit?

Comment: This question does not seem to be about programming, this seems to be an admin issue. You may bet more help at SO's sister site for DBAs at dba.steckexchange.com

Comment: Additional information that may help us to help you: The distribution you're using ("Oracle"/mysql.com, Percona or MariaDB), Server spec (CPUs, Memory), your my.cnf and/or the output of [pt-mysql-summary](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-mysql-summary.html) from [Percona Toolkit](https://www.percona.com/software/database-tools/percona-toolkit) (works with all MySQL distributions)

You may also find [pt-variable-advisor](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-variable-advisor.html) (also from Percona Toolkit) helpful

Comment: Duh!  Don't _increase_ settings when you get "out of memory"!!  Let's see your `my.cnf`.  How much RAM do you have.  Some memory advice:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory